# Scraping with Mechanize

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm having an issue where mechanize isn't producing the same response as a browser. I'm trying to scrape the price from this webpage which allows the addition of items to a basket using a prefilled url.

http://store.nike.com/us/services/jcartService?callback=nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse&action=addItem&lang_locale=en_US&country=US&catalogId=1&productId=463712&price=00.0&siteId=null&line1=Nike+Air+Max+1+Ultra+Moire&line2=Men%27s+Shoe&passcode=null&sizeType=null&skuAndSize=10661133%3A10&qty=1&rt=json&view=3&skuId=10661133&displaySize=14&_=142655682313

What I have is this:

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import cookielib
import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

url='http://store.nike.com/us/services/jcartService?callback=nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse&action=addItem&lang_locale=en_US&country=US&catalogId=1&productId=463712&price=00.0&siteId=null&line1=Nike+Air+Max+1+Ultra+Moire&line2=Men%27s+Shoe&passcode=null&sizeType=null&skuAndSize=10661133%3A10&qty=1&rt=json&view=3&skuId=10661133&displaySize=14&_=142655682313'

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(False)
br.set_handle_robots(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

br.open(url)
pageText=br.open(url).read()
print pageText
```

I then plan to do some basic string parsing to get the price. The problem is that when I scrape the page I get this:

`print pageText`

```
nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse({
    "exceptions": [{
        "property": "catalogRefId",
        "errorcode": "noItemsToAddInStock",
        "message": "Sorry, &#x047E;, this item isn&#39;t available anymore because other shoppers added it to their carts first. But if they don&#39;t check out in the next few minutes, you&#39;ve still got a chance. Please try again shortly. [Code: 420N-00000000]"
    }],
    "status": "failure",
    "order": {
        "id": "dummy",
        "objType": "order",
        "itemQuantity": 0
    }
});
```

When it should be returning something like this as it does in the browser:

```
nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse({
    "status" :"success","order" :{
        "id" :"O1014750586",
        "objType" :"order",
        "itemQuantity" :1,
        "priceInfo" :{
            "currencyFormat" :"$0.00",
            "currency" :"USD",
            "amount" :"75.0",
            ....
}]}]}});
```

I looked into lxml but was rather confused on how to go about it. Is it not possible to properly scrape this page?

Any help would be greeatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the main store page first so that you can be issued with the correct cookies. Then navigate to the required URL:

```
import mechanize

store_url = 'http://store.nike.com'
cart_url = 'http://store.nike.com/us/services/jcartService?callback=nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse&action=addItem&lang_locale=en_US&country=US&catalogId=1&productId=463712&price=00.0&siteId=null&line1=Nike+Air+Max+1+Ultra+Moire&line2=Men%27s+Shoe&passcode=null&sizeType=null&skuAndSize=10661133%3A10&qty=1&rt=json&view=3&skuId=10661133&displaySize=14&_=142655682313'

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open(store_url)
response = br.open(cart_url)
data = response.read()
print data
```

**Output**

```
nike_Cart_hanleJCartResponse({"status" :"success","order" :{"id" :"O1014976420","objType" :"order","itemQuantity" :1,"priceInfo" :{"currencyFormat" :"$0.00","currency" :"USD","amount" :"75.0","isDiscounted" :false,"formattedAmount" :"$75.00","subTotal" :75.0,"formattedSubTotal" :"$75.00","discountAmount" :0.0,"formattedDiscountAmount" :"$0.00","tax" :0.0,"rawSubtotal" :75.0,"formattedRawSubtotal" :"$75.00","formattedTax" :"$0.00","shipping" :0.0,"formattedShipping" :"$0.00","rawShipping" :0.0,"formattedRawShipping" :"$0.00","giftWrap" :0.0,"formattedGiftWrap" :"$0.00","total" :75.0,"formattedTotal" :"$75.00"},"originOfOrder" :"0","transient" :false,"shippingGroups" :[{"id" :"SG1022772456","objType" :"shippingGroup","priceInfo" :{"currencyFormat" :"$0.00","currency" :"USD","amount" :"0.0","isDiscounted" :false,"formattedAmount" :"$0.00","rawShipping" :0.0,"formattedRawShipping" :"$0.00"},"shippingMethod" :"Ground Service","description" :"me","shippingMethodDisplay" :"Standard","commerceItems" :[{"id" :"CI1022253932","objType" :"commerceItem","priceInfo" :{"currencyFormat" :"$0.00","currency" :"USD","amount" :"75.0","isDiscounted" :false,"formattedAmount" :"$75.00","listPrice" :75.0,"formattedListPrice" :"$75.00","salePrice" :0.0,"formattedSalePrice" :"$0.00","onSale" :false,"rawTotalPrice" :75.0,"formattedRawTotalPrice" :"$75.00","giftWrapPrice" :0.0,"formattedGiftWrapPrice" :"$0.00"},"validForCountry" :true,"commerceItemClassType" :"default","quantity" :1,"catalogRefId" :"10661133","catalogId" :"1","product" :{"id" :"463712","view" :"short","displayName" :"Nike Roshe Run Men's Shoe","description" :"Nike Roshe Run Men's Shoe","colorNumber" :"010","activeIndicator" :"ACTIVE","type" :"nikeProduct","styleNumber" :"511881","salePrice" :"75.0","listPrice" :"75.0","employeePrice" :"45.0","onSale" :false,"currency" :"USD","currencyFormat" :"$0.00","formattedListPrice" :"$75.00","formattedSalePrice" :"$75.00","colorDescription" :"Black/Sail/Anthracite","prdGroupId" :"943980","nikeType" :"FOOTWEAR","dynamicAttributes" :{"includepromo" :"GIFTS2014","nikeidmatchstyle" :"704691","width" :"Regular","nikeidmatch" :"true","publishdate" :"05/11/2010","nikeidmatchproductid" :"1094199","divisioncode" :"20","productdisplayorder" :"7","simplecolor" :"BLACK","quantitylimit" :"2","giftwrap" :"true","modelType" :"FOOTWEAR","swatchcolorhex" :"000000","gender" :"Men","classid" :"120001"}},"shipTo" :null,"giftMessage" :null,"giftMessageType" :0,"itemSource" :"SC","sizeType" :"","displaySize" :"14","sizeDescription" :"14","eanNumber" :"00675911199978","colorNumber" :"010","colorDescription" :"Black/Sail/Anthracite"}]}]}});
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't even notice it was a cookie issue. Thank you!